# suggestions for my monitoring system?

Tags: encryption, smtp, udp, portforwarding

I'm a young professional who's into embedded design, IT networking, control/monitoring systems and much more. Currently, I'm developing a monitoring system using a device from Tibbo Techonology, their DS1102.

http://tibbo.com/products/controllers/ds110x/ds1102

It's a programmable device that covers serial and ethernet communications. For my project, its main tasks are serial data collection and database population. Serial communication is done through RS485 and database used is MySQL 5.5. My database is hosted on a public IP which also runs a webserver for the interface while my device is behind a NAT. It connects to the database directly using the public IP.

I'd like to ask for advices so that I can enhance and upgrade it. Right now these are the
questions I'd like to ask.

1. Which is better? Having the server on a public IP or using port forwarding?
   I'm also using it as webserver for the interface of my monitoring system.
2. To communicate with the device (rebooting, changing IP etc), I wrote an application in
   python using UDP (using port 65535 of device) and also set the device to communicate with the application for specific commands. My concern is I want to encrypt the communication between my python app and the device both ways. The only available function for both encrypting and decrypting on the DS1102 is RC4. What are your thoughts on using RC4 for this application? Also, I'm planning to do port forwarding on port 65535 so that I can use my python app from the outside. Can RC4 be reliable for this too? I really want to learn how to use encryptions properly.
3. I'm also planning to implement SMTP for alert messages. Tibbo has a sample code from which I based mine. Problem is, it's on AUTH PLAIN LOGIN. I think I want to turn it to STARTTLS later. Can you recommend some lessons on the algorithm of STARTTLS?
4. What are those details on MAIL FROM:<> and RCPT TO:<>? Because on using the command
   DATA, the programmer can write anyway From: and To: which can make his identity someone else.

That's it for now. Suggestions are very welcome.
You can also share some good reading materials and links. I'm always hungry for learning. :)

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

2.
Encryption substitutes the confidentiality of an arbitrary amount of data (the plaintext) with the confidentiality of a small amount data (the key). In other words, your communication is only as confidential as the key – if the shared secret key leaks out, the encryption is worthless. [More on this.](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/09/27/keep-it-secret-keep-it-safe.aspx)

Also note that plain RC4 provides no authenticity (message integrity). An adversary can modify messages as much as he wants. He can even send his own messages which will be considered perfectly valid by the cipher. Verifying the validity of the messages is is up to the code that parses the messages.

If your messages are simple (only a few bytes or so), an adversary could simply send random bytes until they decrypt such that they form a valid message, without knowing anything about the key. This happens on average after only 100 attempts for a 1-byte message for example.

You will obviously have to use some sort of a nonce to prevent trivial replay attacks.

RC4 is also rather quirky *per se*. I guess you are already aware of the numerous "drop-*n*" variants and so on.

In short, protocol design is perilous. Even experts often get it wrong (look at [WEP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wired_Equivalent_Privacy) for example). The most straightforward way to solve this would be to find hardware that can handle an existing protocol such as [TLS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security).